# ASP.Net Entity Framework one-to-many relationship: How to establish dependency and lazy loading not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, one-to-many

I have two classes. The class `BC_Instance` can have many `BC_InstanceSession` and a `BC_InstanceSession` is **dependent** on a `BC_Instance` and should be deleted when it's relative BC_Instance is deleted.

```
//Instance
public class BC_Instance
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    //sessions
    public ICollection<BC_InstanceSession> sessions { get; set; }
}

//Instance session
public class BC_InstanceSession
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Instance")]
    public int InstanceID { get; set; }
    public virtual BC_Instance Instance { get; set; }
}
```

I have detected a few problems with this configuration. First **Sessions** are not deleted when it's **Instance** is deleted. Is it possible to specify that a session cannot exist without an instance or I need to manually delete them?

**Second** there seems to be a problem in the mapping to the database. A Session has two foreign keys on the Database `InstanceID` and `BC_Instance_ID` as show in the image below: 
[image]

**Finally** Lazy loading does not work. Explicit loading is needed to access the Sessions for an instance (code below)

```
BC_Instance instance = db.BiocloudInstances.Include(i => i.sessions).Where(i => i.ID == id).First();
```

Comment: the lazy loading is not working because you didn't specify `virtual` to your `ICollection`. Like: `public virtual ICollection<BC_InstanceSession> sessions { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the **first** question you can use a `CascadeOnDelete`, something like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
   modelBuilder.Entity<BC_Instance>()
               .HasMany(i => i.sessions) 
               .WithRequired(s => s.Instance) 
               .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
   }
```

For the **second** one, if you look on the `EntityFramework` documentation they specify that a 1-n relationship is used without the `ForeignKey` adnotation. So, because you declare your relationship virtual, EF will add 2 keys. To fix this, remove the `ForeignKey` adnotation and the `public int InstanceID { get; set; }` row. (More on their page [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx))

**Third**, as i specified in the comment,
the lazy loading is not working because you didn't specify `virtual` to your `ICollection`. Like: `public virtual ICollection<BC_InstanceSession> sessions { get; set; }`

Comment: not sure about the modelBuilder though. It wasn't working and I changed it to `modelBuilder.Entity<BC_Instance>()
                .HasMany(i => i.sessions)
                .WithRequired(s => s.Instance)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);`
based on another reference (I'm afraid I don't remember it).

Comment: @nest It was just an example of how to do it, updated the answer with your working code :)